# Log-out app automatically if app is idle for some time

Tags: java, android, session-timeout

I want to logout automatically if app is idle for some time , like session time out , how it can be done in android app?

Comment: How are you maintaining session in APP, tell us that then we can give you an answer.

Comment: for now we are storing token into shared pref and using it for each request, but want to delete it if app is ideal for some time.

Comment: you can use a global timer reference a `countdown timer` and in each activity `onResume` method reset you `timer` and in your `timer` logic when countdown finishes `invalidate` your preferences

Comment: Thanks , Its solved my problem only instead of using onResume() used onUserInteraction() method to reset timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TimerTask` to increment the session timeout variable.

If it reaches some threshold value call `finish()` in your Activity

Reset the  session timeout variable in `onUserInteraction()` of your Activity.

Comment: But I want to invalidate session  if app is ideal for some time like 15 minute etc , don want to invalidate session when user is using app.

Comment: Where you storing session values ? If it is SharedPreferences , clear it when you timeout variable reaches a limit value(Say 15mints)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in below method

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }
```